# MatPlotLib: Scatter with multiple y values to one x value, and regression lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, types

I would like to create a scatter plot in matplotlib to measure the performance of my algorithm.

An example of my data is as follows:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [1, 2, 3]    # corresponding to x = 1
y2 = [4, 5, 6]    # corresponding to x = 2
y3 = [7, 8, 9]    # corresponding to x = 3
y4 = [10, 11, 12] # corresponding to x = 4
y5 = [13, 14, 15] # corresponding to x = 5
```

What data type would be best to represent multiple y values with one x value?

In my example the relation is exponential. Is there a way to plot an exponential regression line in matplotlib?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is related with the data analyses. If I understand correctly, I think you want to have a comparison with every test's time efficiency, but at each test run, they should be at the same test environments (like the same machine, the same input data, etc.) So just give a suggestion, you can use each test's average run time as the standard value to show your test results. Here is some code you can use.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_dim = 4 # number of test
data_points = 100 # number of each test_data_points

data_set = np.random.rand(data_dim,data_points)
time = [ list(range(len(i))) for i in data_set]

norm = np.full((data_dim,data_points),1)
aver = [] # get each test's average value
ndx = 0
for i in norm:
    aver.append(i* sum(data_set[0]) / data_points)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

ndx = 1
for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,2):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,ndx)
        ax.plot(time[ndx-1],data_set[ndx-1],'ko')
        ax.plot(time[ndx-1],aver[ndx-1],'r')
        ax.set_ylim(-1,2)
        ndx += 1

plt.show()
```

The following is the run result. Note, the red solid line is the average of your test time, which will give some senses of your each test.
[image]